# Unable to import module 'lambda_function': No module named 'Crypto'

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, python-packaging, aws-lambda-layers

I have following  python lambda function

**lambda_function.py**

```
from Crypto.Cipher import AES
from Crypto.Util.Padding import pad,unpad
import base64

#CBC with Fix IV

data = 'random text to be encrypted decrypted'
key = 'xxx' #16 char for AES128

#FIX IV
iv =  'yyy'.encode('utf-8') #16 char for AES128

def encrypt(data,key,iv):
        data= pad(data.encode(),16)
        cipher = AES.new(key.encode('utf-8'),AES.MODE_CBC,iv)
        return base64.b64encode(cipher.encrypt(data))

def decrypt(enc,key,iv):
        enc = base64.b64decode(enc)
        cipher = AES.new(key.encode('utf-8'), AES.MODE_CBC, iv)
        return unpad(cipher.decrypt(enc),16)

encrypted = encrypt(data,key,iv)
print('encrypted CBC base64 : ',encrypted.decode("utf-8", "ignore"))

decrypted = decrypt(encrypted,key,iv)
print('decrypted data: ', decrypted.decode("utf-8", "ignore"))

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    encrypt(data, key, iv)
```

I created a lambda function using runtime **python 3.12** and created a **layer** called `custom_encrypt_decrypt` and added this layer to the lambda as shown below,

[image]

When I try to execute the lambda, it throws error,

> "Unable to import module 'lambda_function': No module named 'Crypto'"

---

Firstly, I found that I have to use  **pycryptodome** python library.

**How I uploaded this library to lambda**

1. in my local computer I added the library,

   pip install pycryptodome

It added these two folders in my local

[image]

2. I selected both the folders and created a **.zip** folder.
3. uploaded zip folder to `custom_encrypt_decrypt` layer (and layer is already attached to lambda) - Note: pointing to right layer version.
4. Executed lambda again and getting the same error again n again.

---

**NOTE**: If I run this python code locally, it works using same **pycryptodome** library!

---

Updates:

There is some serious problem and I don't know what is wrong.

I reduced my lambda code to below,

```
import json
from Crypto.Cipher import AES
from Crypto.Util.Padding import pad,unpad
import base64

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    # TODO implement
    return {
        'statusCode': 200,
        'body': json.dumps('Hello from Lambda!')
    }
```

and followed steps suggested by @Roronoa Zoro (for windwos) and now I get below errors

```
{
  "errorMessage": "Cannot load native module 'Crypto.Cipher._raw_ecb': Not found '_raw_ecb.cpython-312-x86_64-linux-gnu.so', Not found '_raw_ecb.abi3.so', Not found '_raw_ecb.so'",
  "errorType": "OSError",
  "requestId": "",
  "stackTrace": [
    "  File \"/var/lang/lib/python3.12/importlib/__init__.py\", line 90, in import_module\n    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)\n",
    "  File \"<frozen importlib._bootstrap>\", line 1381, in _gcd_import\n",
    "  File \"<frozen importlib._bootstrap>\", line 1354, in _find_and_load\n",
    "  File \"<frozen importlib._bootstrap>\", line 1325, in _find_and_load_unlocked\n",
    "  File \"<frozen importlib._bootstrap>\", line 929, in _load_unlocked\n",
    "  File \"<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>\", line 994, in exec_module\n",
    "  File \"<frozen importlib._bootstrap>\", line 488, in _call_with_frames_removed\n",
    "  File \"/var/task/lambda_function.py\", line 2, in <module>\n    from Crypto.Cipher import AES\n",
    "  File \"/opt/python/Crypto/Cipher/__init__.py\", line 27, in <module>\n    from Crypto.Cipher._mode_ecb import _create_ecb_cipher\n",
    "  File \"/opt/python/Crypto/Cipher/_mode_ecb.py\", line 35, in <module>\n    raw_ecb_lib = load_pycryptodome_raw_lib(\"Crypto.Cipher._raw_ecb\", \"\"\"\n",
    "  File \"/opt/python/Crypto/Util/_raw_api.py\", line 315, in load_pycryptodome_raw_lib\n    raise OSError(\"Cannot load native module '%s': %s\" % (name, \", \".join(attempts)))\n"
  ]
}
```

Comment: It just worked after creating packages/modules in Ubuntu machine and then uploading to the layer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was facing the same issue after some troubleshooting, I was able to fix the issue.

- Check the python version in local machine and Lambda (It should be similar) as few packages are not imported properly when different version is there.

Create Zip file in below mentioned path:

- Create Virtual environment for python3.

```
python3 -m venv venv
source venv/bin/activate
```

- Create a directory with name "python"

```
mkdir python
cd python
```

- Install you packages in this folder.

```
pip3 install pycryptodome -t .
```

- Once installed Check the packages.
- Create ZIP file for python directory

```
cd .. 
zip -r deployment_name.zip python
```

- Now you can upload the .zip file to you AWS Lambda Layer.

**Make sure the ZIP file is created for all folder available in python folder Don't miss out any files or folders it may be our main package may be dependent on it.**

---

**For Windows**

- Using power shell or Command Prompt perform following steps (admin privileges):

```
mkdir layers
cd layers
mkdir python
cd python
pip3 install pycryptodome -t ./
```

- Now open the python folder in file explorer.
- Zip the python folder along with its child folders.
- Now you are good to go and upload it as layer in AWS.

**It will great if you have Linux Machine or Create an EC2 Instance with Ubuntu AMI and Copy the Content to S3, the you can upload it from S3 bucket to AWS lambda layer directly.**

Update:

- I have Created Similar Scenario in my environment:
- I installed the Crypto library in my local machine(Ubuntu) as per above mentioned steps.
  [image: Installation Image]
- Created a Zip.
  [image: Zip File]
- Uploaded the ZIP file to create layer and added layer to lambda
  [image: Lamabda Functions]
- It worked as Charm:
  [image: Output]

**Make Sure to add the layer to lambda**
**My Python version was 3.10 for local and Lambda's python**

Comment: My local system is windows: I follwed what you mentioned and got : `"errorMessage": "Cannot load native module 'Crypto.Cipher._raw_ecb': Not found '_raw_ecb.cpython-312-x86_64-linux-gnu.so', Not found`

Comment: Locally I have Python 3.12.2

Comment: For windows `source venv/bin/activate` didn't work so I did `.\venv\Scripts\activate.bat`. Then I created `python` folder. At this point, I can see `python` folder and `venv` folders side by side. I ran `pip install pycryptodome -t .` it installed two folders in `python` folder.

Comment: `zip -r deployment_name.zip python` doesn't work with windows. So I manually zipped `python` & `venv` (which are side by side). So finally I have one zipped contains `python` and `venv` folders inside. Is that correct ?

Comment: Hii @micronyks, I will update my answer as per Windows OS, Allow me few minutes

Comment: Yes yes, sure why not...

Comment: Thanks for all your help but unfortunately I'm not able to run it. I updated my error msg in original question in updated section.

Comment: Hii @micronyks I have tested the same Code and packages with steps i provide(Linux) and it worked, Might be your layer is not built properly or it is not added to lambda.

I have updated the Answer with Snapshots

Comment: does it matter I use python 3.12 runtime in lambda ? Also In layer, I select 3.12 runtime

Comment: Not really, In my local I had Python 3.10 Installed, So I used it for lambda deployment as well. Just make sure the pyhton version for local machine and lambda deployment is similar, For some packages the python version plays important role.

Comment: I don't know how it worked in your case but for me, I followed your instructions on Linux/Ubuntu machine and then it worked for me. For future readers, my ubuntu machine had 3.10 version and my lambda uses  3.12 and still the package worked.

Answer (score 0):

If the the zip file wasn’t packed with the correct structure, AWS won’t find your libraries. The structure has to be created as following:[image]

You can check full desciption in link below:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/packaging-layers.html#packaging-layers-paths

Comment: Tried but seems like making some mistake. Not able to resolve.